# cx_freeze - the exe returns undescriptive error on sqldf

Tags: pandasql

Trying to create exe for my script, i am using pandasql and sqldf to create sql queries against 2 csv files for matching.after the build, when i run the .exe file, s screen with list of errors is returned as per image provided.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated!

[cx_Freeze: Python error in the main script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xScsI.png)

Comment: Please add the error message in text form to your question

Comment: Hi Nico - thanks, I am unable to get the errors in a form that i can copy, a screen is return, please click on the "cx_Freeze: Python error in the main script" link on my message